# Why are these korbanos waved?

Tags: shavuos, korban, mincha-meal-offering, bikkurim-first-fruits, tzaraas-negaim

A few offerings are waved (moved upward, downward, back, and forth) as a part of the process of offering them. If I'm not mistaken, the following is a complete list:

- The *asham* of the *m'tzora*, while it's still alive, along with the oil he brings.
- The fats destined for the *mizbeach*, and the *chaze v'shok* (breast and leg), of an individual's *sh'lamim*.
- The *kivse Atzeres* (sheep brought specially on *Shavuos*), while alive, along with the bread brought with them.
- The *kivse Atzeres*'s fats destined for the mizbeach.
- The *omer*.
- The *mincha* of a *sota*.
- *Bikurim*.

Why these specifically? What's special about these *korbanos* (and *bikurim*) that has to do with waving?

Note that I'm not asking how we know these are waved: in each case, there's a *pasuk* from which we derive the *halacha*. Rather, I'm asking why God commanded that these be waved.

Comment: See [Shemot 38:24](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0238.htm#24), 29.

Comment: You forgot to include the lulav on your list.

Comment: @DoubleAA, also the _l'viyim_. And _hosha'nos_. But I meant to include only _korbanos_ (and, well, _bikurim_ are like _korbanos_).

Comment: I know the lulav is not a korban. But I don't think it is coincidental that it is the only thing waved aside from these korbanot especially in light of lulav bamikdash kol shivah, mitzva habaah ba'aveira which many rishonim limit to kodshim (see the pasuk that the gemara sukka30a brings as a proof), the meimra of r abahu on sukkah 45a going on b, and other evidence.

Comment: @DoubleAA, _lulav_ is (a) not "the only thing waved" (I gave examples of the _l'viyim_ and _hosha'nos_) and (b) waved in a process called _nianua_, not _t'nufa_ like the _korbanos_, which makes it sound (to me) like its waving's in a different class than _korbanos_'. That said, if someone can offer a reason that applies to the things I asked about and _lulav_, too, that'll be great!

Comment: If anyone waves the hoshanot it's only agav the lulav. Also, why don't you think the leviyim are gufa a korban? They are being consecrated and offered to the benefit of the mikdash.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13310

Comment: See Mishnah in Menachos 61a that gives the list of things that need waving: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=61&format=pdf

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29337

Answer (score 2):

The Gemorah in [Menachos 62a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=62&format=pdf) says the reason is to stop "bad winds":

אמר רב חמא בר עוקבא אמר רבי יוסי בר רבי חנינא מוליך ומביא כדי לעצור רוחות רעות מעלה ומוריד כדי לעצור טללים רעים

Although I realize this is not an answer as to why "davka" (specifically) the ones that are waved.

Comment: Note that that passage is referring only to the _kivse Atzeres_ and the bread brought with them, not to the other things. (Cf. _Tosafos_.)

Comment: @msh210 Thanks for pointing that out. I discussed this with a few Talmidei Chachamim and no one pointed out the Tosfos...

Answer (score 2):

I found something that might be helpful in your search. The *Meam Loez* discusses why the *chazeh v'shok* are waved (Vayikra 7:30):

> The Hebrew word for chest is *chazeh*, which also has the connotation of seeing. We thus find, "His eyes shall see (*ye-chezu*), his eyelids shall discern the children of man" (Psalms 11:4). This teaches that God's eyes and eyelids know people's deeds and nothing is hidden from them. That is why the chest (*chazeh*) is waved in all four directions: east, west, north, and south. The fat, inner organs, and the kidneys also teach that God looks into the innermost recesses and hearts of all people. The leg is waved up and down. This teaches that God has the power to raise and to lower.

There most be more explanations on the other offerings, but perhaps this can contribute to your answer.

Comment: Can you post a link to this on Hebrew Books?

Comment: Hebrew Books doesn't have Meam Loez for Vayikra. The English version is found in the Torah Anthology, Vol. 11, Parashat Tzav Ch. 7, pg. 176 translated from the Ladino by R. Aryeh Kaplan.