# What is the significance of sprinkling blood on/around the Mizbeahh?

Tags: korban, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, blood, parashat-vayikra

Parashat WaYiqra details certain methods of sprinkling the blood of qorbanot on or around the Mizbeahh (and the Parokhet for that matter). For example, WaYiqra [1:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0301.htm#5), [1:11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0301.htm#11), [1:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0301.htm#15), [3:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0303.htm#2), [3:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0303.htm#8), [3:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0303.htm#13), [4:6-7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0304.htm#6), [4:17-18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0304.htm#17), [4:25](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0304.htm#25), [4:30](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0304.htm#30), [4:34](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0304.htm#34), [5:9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0305.htm#9).

Without delving into the significance specific to each protocol (e.g. Mizbeahh walls, Mizbeahh corners), what is the overall significance of sprinkling the blood of qorbanot on or around the Mizbeahh?

Comment: More general question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13310

Answer (score 5):

[R' Samson Raphael Hirsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch)'s [Commentary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0910818126) on some of the verses you cite provides extensive treatments of particular lessons to be derived from each kind of blood-sprinking or -pouring, starting with seven pages on the one introduced in Vayikra 1:5. My understanding, after looking through some of these for general ideas about the meaning of blood-sprinkling, is that:

- The blood represents the totality of the korban-bringers life-force (*nefesh*).
- Sprinkling represents the dedication of the korban-bringer's expenditure of energy toward whatever concept is symbolized by the target of the sprinkling.

If you are interested in learning more about the detailed symbolisms and lessons available in these procedures, I strongly recommend study of R' Hirsch's extensive commentary on the applicable verses.

Comment: Thanks for the research and detailed answer, @Isaac Moses! Can you help me understand a bit better what you mean by "the blood [representing] the _totality_ of the [qorban]-bringer's life force"?

Answer (score -2):

Sforno says -- my life must be centered around the service of God.

Comment: Sorry, @Shalom, I don't quite see how this answers the question.