# Why some Korbanot male while others are female?

Tags: korban, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

Why do some korbanot need to be brought as male animals, and some as female animals?

Comment: Some can be brought as either FWIW. Also FWIW female animals are only found in private offerings, never communal ones.

Comment: "Because the Torah said so" - is that a valid answer?

Comment: More general: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13310

Answer (score 4):

[Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) explains that the animal brought, and its gender, corresponds to the greatness of the sin committed:

**Guide for the Perplexed 3:46**

> The greater the sin which a person had committed, the lower was the
>   species from which the sin-offering was brought. The offering for
>   worshipping idols in ignorance was only a she-goat, whilst for other
>   sins an ordinary person brought either a ewe-lamb or a she-goat (Lev.
>   iv. 27-35), the females bring, as a rule, in every species, inferior
>   to the males. There is no greater sin than idolatry, and also no
>   inferior species than a she-goat. The offering of a king for sins
>   committed ignorantly was a he-goat (ibid. vers. 22-26), as a mark of
>   distinction. The high priest and the Synhedrion, who only gave a wrong
>   decision in ignorance, but have not actually committed a sin, brought
>   a bull for their sin-offering (ibid. ver. 3-21), or a he-goat, when
>   the decision referred to idolatry (Num. xv. 27-26). The sins for which
>   guilt-offerings were brought were not as bad as transgressions that
>   required a sin-offering. The guilt-offering was therefore a ram, or a
>   lamb, so that the species as well as the sex were superior in this
>   latter case, for the guilt-offering was a male sheep. For the same
>   reason we see the burnt-offering, which was entirely burnt upon the
>   altar, was selected from the superior sex; for only male animals were
>   admitted as burnt-offerings. ([Friedlander translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp182.htm))