# Significance of mussaf korbanos

Tags: korban, symbols-symbology, musaf

Is there a general overview and explanation available anywhere (Chazal, rishonim, achronim, contemporary) about how the system of mussaf korbanos are built?

I mean, the significance and meaning behind the numbers and different species that are brought, explaining the connections between the various holidays.

The closest match I could find is from [R. Menachem Leibtag](https://tanach.org/bamidbar/pin/pins2.htm), which is explaining three categories of the mussaf korbanos, and how combining two of them is resulting the third one. This is indeed really impressing, but I am still missing some similar ideas about the basic information, like: why that amount of ox, ram, lamb on these days.

(There is a fantastic Midrash regarding Chanukas haMizbeach (Bamidbar 7:12-83, p.767 in Artscroll Stone Chumash) which matches a lot of korbanos-symbolism to events in Bereishis. There it matches ox-ram-lamb to Avraham-Yitzchak-Yaakov. I especially wonder whether the symbolism of mussaf korbanos have a consistent, or even just a similar explanation/matching like this.)

Comment: Subset of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13310/170